# URDF origins tags

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm building my first urdf, and I noticed that I can define the origin tag on the visual, collision elements but also on the link element. So I am wondering if there's a best practice ?

For instance, if I have two 10cm x 10cm x 10cm boxes one on the other, I could define the origin on the link tag with y = 5cm and the origin of the visual/collision tags at y = 5cm too but this is not really DRY, so I would probably only use the origin of the link tag only with y = 10cm, but which solution is better ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228098/urdf-origins-tags/) by [LiohAu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22186/liohau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Blatant self promotion: check out my ROSCon talk. http://wustl.probablydavid.com/entry093.html

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-03-03**:
Nice one :)

**Comment by [LiohAu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22186/liohau/) on 2016-03-03**:
If I understood correctly what you are saying at 17:30, using only the origin of the joint tag is not a problem for fixed joints right ? Also, in rviz, when you show the axis, which axis does it shows, the joint one ?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2016-03-06**:
Using only the origin tag is probably not a problem. It shows the joint origin, which is the origin of the child link.

**Comment by [LiohAu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22186/liohau/) on 2016-03-08**:
Since an URDF with a single link also displays axis, I assume that an implicit joint is created for the first link  in an URDF right ? And if i'm right, this joint between that URDF link and an hardcoded link created/hardcoded somewhere by the ROS system ?

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-23**:
i have one urdf file and my link is laying on ground and i want to make it normal to the ground how i can do may u help me sir ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on how you define the visual and collision elements. For example, you have a `base_link` which is in the center of the robot. If the origin of the robot mesh is not defined at the center, you will see that the mesh does not match for the actual definition.

Example: let us say that you have a cylinder-shaped robot, and `base_link` origin is in the center of the bottom face. If your cylinder mesh is centered in the center of mass (for instance) of the cylinder, you would have to move the origin of the visualization/collision in the Z direction by `height/2`.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2016-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-23**:
i have one urdf file and my link is laying on ground and i want to make it normal to the ground how i can do may u help me sir ?

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2018-04-27**:
@lagankapoor you have to rotate it. I would say that is a very basic URDF feature, so if you follow the tutorials carefully you will see how to do it. If you continue having issues, open a new question instead of using the comment section of a different question.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-04-27**:
@Javier V. Gómez Sir i have solved that issue after this and create my URDF file with Solidworks .